# Ползунок при передвижении которого будет происходить какой либо эффект

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Добрый день! Появилась идея, не совсем понимаю как реализовать.

Как сделать ползунок при передвижении которого будет происходить какой либо эффект?
К примеру, когда ползунок установлен на 0, картинки не видно; а когда я его начинаю передвигать она постепенно появляется, и соответственно при движении в обратную сторону - аналогично.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложу вариант именно с ползунком, а не со скроллом:

```js
let onChange = function(){
 let range = document.getElementById('Range');
 document.getElementById('Wrapper').style.width = range.value + "px";
 document.getElementById('Window_size').innerHTML = range.value;
}
document.getElementById('Range').addEventListener('input', function(){  
 onChange();
}); 
onChange();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #B0BBBF;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #FEFAE0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 60px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 30px auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper .window-size {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.slider-block {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="Wrapper" class="wrapper">
 <div id="Window_size" class="window-size"></div>
</div>
<div class="slider-block">
 <input id="Range" type="range"  min="320" value="500" max="1000" step="1"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот красивый пример для реализации того что вы задумали. в `javascript` есть событие для `scroll`, Я добавил два блока `div` и в них сделал скроллбар.
После перехвата скролла взял позицию с лева скроллбара с помощью функции `scrollLeft` и меняю `opacity` картинки.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('.scrolling').on('scroll', function(event){
  var scroll_img_opacity = $(this).scrollLeft()/100;
  $('.scroll_img').css({opacity: scroll_img_opacity});
 });
});
```

```css
.scrolling{
  width: 200px;
  height: 15px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.scrolling>div{
  width: 283px;
  height: 15px;
}
.scroll_img{
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.christenseninstitute.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Code-photo-Edit-cropped.jpg" class="scroll_img" />
<div class="scrolling">
  <div></div>
</div>
```